# Монетизация desktop application

Tags: java, javafx, реклама, монетизация, встроенная-реклама

А можно ли сделать интеграцию рекламы в приложение на базе JavaFX ?
И вообще в приложение написанное на java для десктопа?
Сколько не искал, все мануалы только о монетизации сайтов да приложений для смарфтонов, а как и какую рекламу можно интегрировать в своё приложение для PC\MAC?

И где можно распространять своё приложение ?